# Proxy error when using docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose, proxy, mern

I keep getting the following error

```
Proxy error: Could not proxy request /getProducts from localhost:3002 to http://localhost:3001.
```

when trying to 'docker compose up' my docker-compose.yml file for a mern application.

Here is the file:

```
version: "3.8"

services:

  mongodb:
    image: "mongo"
    volumes:
      - data:/data/db

  backend:
    image: "{path to docker hub image}" 
    container_name: armoireBackend
    ports:
      - "3001:3001"
    volumes:
      - logs:/app/logs
      - ./backend:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    depends_on:
      - mongodb

  frontend:
    image: "{path to docker hub image}" 
    ports:
      - "3002:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/src:/app/src
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    depends_on:
      - backend
volumes:
  data:
  logs:
```

My react's package.json:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "proxy":"http://backend:3001",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.4",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.4",
    "@mui/material": "^5.10.9",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@trendmicro/react-sidenav": "^0.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.1.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "transformIgnorePatterns": ["node_modules\/(?!axios)"]
  }
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong - my proxy in the package.json file is now referring to the name of the container at backend, but still processes requests to localhost/3001?
I have also tried changing the proxy to

```
"proxy": {
    "/api":  {
        "target": "http://backend:3001"
    }
},
```

and

```
  "proxy": "http://host.docker.internal:3001",
```

as well as adding a slash at the end of the original http://localhost:3001 proxy.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: read [this article](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development). According to the documentation, your request must look like **"/api/todos"**. From your description your request should be as following `/api/getProducts` If you desire to set up your own path, use a manual set-up like [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/#configuring-the-proxy-manually)

Comment: [@shiz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18545747/shiz) If it's solved your problem, I'll post it as a solution and select it as a solution. Thanks.

Comment: @StanislavPyshevskyi I still trying this, but each time I keep getting the same error, despite the addition of /api

Comment: What is the final backend endpoint you declared in the backend code?